# How to seed data with ActionText has_rich_text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

In my model, I have:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_rich_text :description
  ...
 end
```

In my seeds.rb:

```
@listing = Listing.new(
      title: 'CODE VEIN',
      price: 59.99 * 100,
      description:  "<p>#{Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(number: 30).join(' ')}</p>",
      seller_id: seller.id,
      release_date: Date.parse('Sep 26, 2019'),
      status: :active,
      esrb: 'MATURE'
    )
```

Listing.description comes up nil, causing my NOT NULL constraint to error.

I've debugged with pry, and tried `@listing.description.body= text` or `@listing.description.body = ActionText::Content.new(text)`, both still cause the listing#description to be nil.

This is an API Only project, but I use Trix RTE in the front-end react app. Is there a specific method to seed rich_text columns?

Comment: The issue was with uuid as primary keys instead of integer ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionText stores the actual contents in a seperate `action_text_rich_texts` table which uses a polymorphic assocation to link back to the model that its attached to.

```
# This migration comes from action_text (originally 20180528164100)
class CreateActionTextTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :action_text_rich_texts do |t|
      t.string     :name, null: false
      t.text       :body, size: :long
      t.references :record, null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false

      t.timestamps

      t.index [ :record_type, :record_id, :name ], name: "index_action_text_rich_texts_uniqueness", unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

The JavaScript component of ActionText (which is really the whole point) automatically sends AJAX requests when the user user interacts with Trix to create/update the row in the `action_text_rich_texts` table even before you have saved the record you're creating.

When you then submit the form you're actually submitting the id to the row on the `action_text_rich_texts` table and not the contents. Then when you save your model it updates the corresponding row on `action_text_rich_texts`  with the `record_type` and `record_id` from the model. Its a pretty awkward solution that is built around the idea of never having to add columns to your model.

I don't really see the point in using ActionText in an API as the whole point is to add a quick and dirty Trix implementation to classical rails apps. You really should be able to solve this with just a single text column instead. Especially as that will let you access the contents without joining.

Comment: So remove the column from the db? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'm using it, because I still need a rich text editor in the front-end. ckeditor was my real choice, but built in support sounded better

Comment: I'm guessing it could share the same strange behavior as ActionStorage (which is a very similar design) and `#description` will return nil until you save the record as its actually querying the action_text_rich_texts  table (and not an attribute).

Comment: After removing the :description column, I can access the test by saving it as `@listing.description.body = @listing.description.body ="<p>#{Faker::Lorem.unique.paragraphs(number: 30).join(' ')}</p>"`.

Then, do `@listing.description.body.to_plain_text` or `@listing.description.body.to_trix_html`

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work for me:

```
15.times do
  Post.create!(title: Faker::Book.unique.title)
end
```

then

```
Post.all.each do |post|
  ActionText::RichText.create!(record_type: 'Post', record_id: post.id, name: 'content', body: Faker::Lorem.sentence)
end
```

To read:

```
Post.first.content.body.to_plain_text
```

or:

```
Post.first.content.body.to_trix_html
```

...as stated above by OP.

Source:
https://linuxtut.com/rails6-input-the-initial-data-of-actiontext-using-seed-9b4f2/

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else going on with your code. Maybe if you share your migration and the complete Listing class file it might be easier to spot what's going on.

Here are a few steps to make sure you got it right:

1. Create a brand new rails app (you can delete it later):

```
rails new testrichtext -d mysql --api
```

2. Create the db

```
cd testrichclient
rake db:create
```

3. Create the model

```
rails g model listing description:text
```

4. Change your newly created migration file to make sure the column is not null:

```
class CreateListings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :listings do |t|
      t.text :description, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

5. Run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

6. Now you should be able to log in into the console, and create a new listing with something as the description:

```
rails c
```

And inside console:

```
l = Listing.new(description: "<p>Something nice</p>")
l.save!
Listing.first.description
```

As you can see, this is enough to save/seed a new listing with rich text. So anything you may have going on there should be something you're causing somewhere else, by adding a validation differently, or callbacks. Hard to say without looking at the entire file

Comment: There is something else involved - its called ActionText and stores the content on completely differnet table.